# Is there a writeToFile equivalent for Swift 3's 'Data' type?

Tags: swift, nsdata, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I've some code which returns the new iOS 10 / Swift 3 NSData replacement(?) type: Data

```
if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.8) { ... }
```

I want to write this image to disk, however NSData's `writeToFile:` method is not present for this class. It does have a `writeToURL:` method, but that doesn't seem to work with a file path (and appending component).

Can anyone clarify how I would now do this, as used to be the case in Swift 2:

```
jpegData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use `write(to: fileURL)`.

For example:

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
    .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent("test.jpg")

do {
    try jpegData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Or, if you really are stuck with a `path`, convert that to a `URL`:

```
do {
    try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .atomic)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

But, generally, it's preferable to use `URL` references throughout your code nowadays, retiring the use of path strings.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks Rob. And thanks for making the switch to .atomic.

Comment: Apple seems to be moving towards URL-based file APIs and deprecating(?) the path(String)-based ones.

Comment: Largely so, yes, but with some odd exceptions (e.g. [`UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624112-init), but no file URL rendition).

Comment: Does not work if file path(name, folders) contains unicode characters.
Solution is:
path.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed)

Comment: @IurieManea - Good point. Yes, if you’re passing a path or URL string to `URL(string:)` or `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`, you have to make sure the string is properly percent escaped. However, if you use methods like `let fileURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(".dat")`, it does the percent encoding for you.